# No Sendmail but ISPConfig Postfix

Tags: centos, php, postfix, sendmail

This is what php uses to send php mail with the php mail() function:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").                                                                                                                                   
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path 


sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  //sendmail command to send mail
```

but its not sending the mail to the recipient and I get this in the maillog:

```
Dec  1 12:52:09 srvload1 postfix/qmgr[25215]: D3982162BB6: from=<sxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>, size=524, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 12:52:09 srvload1 postfix/qmgr[25215]: warning: connect to transport private/[127.0.0.1]: No such file or directory
Dec  1 12:52:09 srvload1 postfix/error[25563]: D3982162BB6: to=<sxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.03/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

warning: connect to transport private/[127.0.0.1]: ? and it gets queued. It doesn't send.

my server admin told me we don't have sendmail installed and I don't want to have it install it on the server, it may disrupt our service.

is there a way to send php mail() without sendmail? The server runs ISPConfig CentOS Postfix and I think Procmail

```
[root@srvload1 ~]# which procmail
/usr/bin/procmail

[root@srvload1 ~]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a number of false assumptions here but the short and pointed answer is that your Postfix configuration is hosed and needs to be corrected.

With the information you provide, I can't tell you how.  Perhaps update your question to include pertinent snippets from your Postfix config (or maybe post a new, better focused question, and delete this one).  Basically we'd need to see anything non-standard from your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and especially anything involving the `private/[127.0.0.1]` transport.  Other transport configurations could be useful for context as well.

You don't need to install Sendmail but you do need to have a working configuration for outgoing mail.

`/usr/sbin/sendmail` is actually a Postfix compatibility wrapper which implements the basic Sendmail functionality.  For legacy reasons, `sendmail` is the canonical name for this, even though Sendmail the MTA is no longer the dominant or standard MTA.

Procmail is unrelated to outgoing mail (unless you have a very customized config, in which case you should document it).